# "To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')" What to do?

Tags: ios, flutter, signing

I received this error when trying to build iOS app on a real iPhone and not on the Simulator. This was part of the error message:

> **To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')**

All the places I looked for help didn't have any tips.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I was using a VPN on my PC when trying to build and deploy to my test device.
Solution was to just disable my VPN.

Apple might be blocking requests over a VPN when signing an App.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate in your flutter folder to directory `/ios/` and open `Runner.xcworkspace` (the white one not the blue one) in xCode.

Then in project navigator (cmd+1) select `Runner` and go to build settings tab called 'signing and capabilities' and manage your signing there to get the account and automatic signing set up, build from xcode (cmd+r).

Once this signing is set up and working once you're good to go, you may now start building from VSCode or Android Studio or wherever. Quit xCode and open original flutter project files.

Enjoy!